# Creating dictionary from a numpy array "ValueError: too many values to unpack"

Tags: numpy

I am trying to create a dictionary from a relatively large numpy array. I tried using the dictionary constructor like so:

```
elements =dict((k,v) for (a[:,0] , a[:,-1]) in myarray)
```

I am assuming I am doing this incorrectly since I get the error: `"ValueError: too many values to unpack"`

The numPy array looks like this:

```
[  2.01206281e+13  -8.42110000e+04  -8.42110000e+04 ...,   0.00000000e+00
    3.30000000e+02  -3.90343147e-03]
```

I want the first column `2.01206281e+13` to be the key and the last column `-3.90343147e-03` to be the value for each row in the array

Am I on the right track/is there a better way to go about doing this?

Thanks

Edit: let me be more clear I want the first column to be the key and the last column to be the value. I want to do this for every row in the numpy array

Comment: It would be helpful to let us know that you are using NumPy arrays and what their dimensions are.

Comment: So you only want to use the first and last value? What about the values in between?

Comment: @MarcodeWit hThe values in between are arbitrary I don't need them the array was generated from a large text file containing data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a hard question on answer without knowing what exactly myarray is, but this might help you get started.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(3, 2))
>>> a
array([[1, 6],
       [9, 3],
       [2, 8]])
>>> dict(a)
{1: 6, 2: 8, 9: 3}
```

or

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(3, 5))
>>> a
array([[9, 7, 4, 4, 6],
       [8, 9, 1, 6, 5],
       [7, 5, 3, 4, 7]])
>>> dict(a[:, [0, -1]])
{7: 7, 8: 5, 9: 6}
```

Comment: +1 for solving it without proper input data from the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
elements = dict( zip( * [ iter( myarray ) ] * 2 ) )
```

What we see here is that we create an iterator based on the myarray list. We put it in a list and double it. Now we've got the same iterator bound to the first and second place in a list which we give as arguments to the zip function which creates a list of pairs for the dict creator.